# instruct elasticsearch to return random results from different types

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an index in ES with say 3 types A,B,C. Each type holds 1000 products. When the user makes a query with no scoring , then ES returns first all results from A, then all from B and then all from C.

What I need is to present mixed results from the 3 types.

I looked into the random scoring but it s not quite what I need.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need randomness or simple 3 results from a type? Three results from each type could be realized through the top hits aggregation. First you aggregate by the **_type** field, then the top hits aggregation is applied:

```
{
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "query": {
        "match_all": {
        }
      },
      "random_score": {
        "seed": 137677928418000
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "all_type": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "_type"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "by_top_hit": {
          "top_hits": {
            "size": 3
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Edit: I added random scoring, to get random results, I think to get special numbers of documents for each **_type** is difficult, a solution is probably to get just enough from all **_type** fields.

Comment: Hi, I need to present all the results from the 3 types in a mixed order. Say X results from A, then Y from B, Z from C, .. from B, etc...It would also be nice if I could display them random order, but since I dont have session management I m not able to provide a seed.

Comment: You could set a different seed for each ES request, just get a random number for seed field in your developing environment before each request.

Comment: Right , that would be a solution but what about pagination. I need the user to see consistent results between the pages. If I use a random seed each time, then each page will produce different results every time. On the other hand as I said I dont have session management